# Paired T-test or Linear Mixed Model or what else?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, mean, repeated-measures, paired-data

I have measured 8 different features on the same mice on three different days. I want to compare the means of those 3 days based on the features.

I have executed paired T-tests for each feature in the following way: Day1Feature1 compared to Day2Feature1, Day1Feature2 compared to  Day2Feature2, etc. Therefore, as far as I know, after I compare all of the combinations I can see the differences between the days.

On the other hand, one of my colleague suggested that I should use Linear Mixed Models in a case like this.

Which approach would be better in this case, and why?

Comment: How many mice? can you show us a plot?

Answer (score 0):

With three separate tests you get multiplicity problems, with a mixed model (with mice as a random effect) you get only one test of the null hypothesis that there is no difference between days. (OK, one test per feature) That is probably why your colleague suggested this.

**EDIT**  Frank Harrell in a comment below criticizes the use of mixed models in this case, and prefers some Markov model. For an answer of his with more details, see [What are the assumptions that need to be checked for multilevel logistic regression and for multilevel ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506043/what-are-the-assumptions-that-need-to-be-checked-for-multilevel-logistic-regress)

Comment: Yes; the use of individual $t$-tests when analyzing longitudinal data is not a good idea.  The correlation pattern in the data is unlikely to be what random effect models expect and is more likely to be correctly modeled using a serial correlation model (generalized least squares or Markov model).